# How to compare histograms of two Images?

Tags: image-processing, histograms

Is there any function in Mathematica that I can use for comparing the image histogram ? There is a built-in function in OpenCV `cv2.compareHist` for distance measures like chi-squared, correlation, intersection and Bhattacharya distance, but what about Mathematica?

Comment: How about starting with ImageHistogram?

Comment: I know. But the point of my question is how you compare ImageHistogram of 2 Images for classification tasks ? There is a build-in function in OpenCV for distance measure like Chi-sqr, Correlation, intersection and BHATTACHARYYA distance , but what's about Mathematica ?

Comment: `ImageDistance` seems to implement these histogram comparisons: MutualInformationVariation, NormalizedMutualInformationVariation, DifferenceNormalizedEntropy, EarthMoverDistance

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [Niki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/niki-estner)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172109/how-to-compare-histograms-of-two-images#comment451967_172109):

> `ImageDistance` seems to implement these histogram comparisons:
>   `"MutualInformationVariation"`, `"NormalizedMutualInformationVariation"`,
>   `"DifferenceNormalizedEntropy"`, `"EarthMoverDistance"`.

`ImageDistance` can be used to compare image histograms.